# What is the Minimum permission the Configuration Wizards' Service Account need to have on the Database

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database, database, sharepoint-farm

we have installed a new sharepoint enterprise server 2013. and now i want to run the "Central Administration >> Configuration Wizards". where i am asked to select the Service Account which will be used during the Configuration Wizards, but my question is what are the minimum permission this service account need to have inside the database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 1st you have to login with the farm admin account in order to start
   config wizard
2. The account which will run service should be domain account. Rest sharepoint will fix the permission for that account.

[Check this blog for better understanding](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-service-accounts-best-practices-explained.html)

Comment: You mean the service account should be a domain account inside the sharepoint windows server and the database server ?

Comment: Domain account means it is active directory account, like any other account